# why setDecorations divide TextEditorDecorationType into ViewLines and ViewOverlays?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

```js
    const codeDecoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
                border: "outset",
                borderRadius: "5px",
            })
    state.activeEditor.setDecorations(codeDecoration, start, end);
```

```js
    const getEnlargeDecoration = () => vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    textDecoration: `display: inline-block; font-size: ${size}px; position: relative; top: 0.1em;`,
            }));
    state.activeEditor.setDecorations(codeDecoration, start, end);
```

Source code in [markless/extension.js at master · Sean10/markless](https://github.com/Sean10/markless/blob/master/src/extension.js).

When i preview the rendered html, i found css `border` in div `class="view-overlays"`, but `font-size: ${size}px; position: relative; top: 0.1em;` in div `class="view-lines`.

When i introduce the same range to `setDecoration`, i expect the border css and font-size css are on the same div.

Can anyone explain how to deal with this, or why are `viewOverlays` and `viewLines` so designed?

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion [Border do not match correctly if the font size if too big or small · Issue #33 · leodevbro/vscode-blockman](https://github.com/leodevbro/vscode-blockman/issues/33) which has the same problem with me.

Accoriding to [Get editor line height (px) and character space-width (px) by VSCode API · Issue #125341 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125341), we known `ViewOverlays` now don't expose API which could realize `border` integrated with `fontSize`.